# import org.json not working in android studio but works through command line

Tags: android, json, android-studio

I want to add

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

These three in a class in Android studio.

I added the the dependency into the build.gradle file.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.json:json:20150729'
}
```

But its not working. I get the following error in my Android Class.

```
Cannot resolve the symbol 'json'
```

When I compile through terminal I am not getting any errors. But when I compile by using Android Studio, I get errors. Why is it so ??

What should I do to fix this ?

Comment: I don't know the exact reason but I suspect your dependency is not working correctly for some reason. Focus on that.

Comment: CanadianCoder is right. If you set up correctly, there is no need to add any lines to gradle for JSON. They are default classes.

Comment: Try cleaning the caches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted the `caches` folder in the `.gradle` directory under home and also in my project directory. It solved my problem. It took some time to build the project afterwards, but it fixed the issue.